# Entity update fails on unique index because of value in record deleted in the same SaveChanges

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Given the following Persons table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    NationalCode INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY ([PersonID] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Persons]
    ON [dbo].[Persons]([NationalCode] ASC) WHERE ([NationalCode] IS NOT NULL);
GO
```

and the following corresponding entity class:

```vb
Public Class Person
    Property ID As Integer
    Property Name As String
    Property NationalCode As Integer?
End Class
```

the following code fails at `SaveChanges`:

```vb
Dim dcx = New MyDataContext
Dim person1 = dcx.Persons.Find(128581)
Dim person2 = dcx.Persons.Find(128603)
person2.NationalCode=person1.NationalCode '200362226
dcx.Persons.Remove(person1)
dcx.SaveChanges
```

on the index with the following error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Persons' with unique index 'IX_Persons'. The duplicate key value is (200362226).
>   The statement has been terminated.

How can I resolve this (without removing the first record, calling `SaveChanges` and only then modifying the second record)?

N.B. Does [`Index(IsUnique=True)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index) have any effect here?

---

In C#:

```cs
public class Person {
    int ID {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    int NationalCode {get;set;}
}

var dcx = new MyDataContext();
var person1 = dcx.Persons.Find(128581);
var person2 = dcx.Persons.Find(128603);
person2.NationalCode = person1.NationalCode; //200362226
dcx.Persons.Remove(person1);
dcx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force EF to execute the delete statement first. The only way to get it done, and in one transaction, is by wrapping the statements in a `TrasactionScope` and calling `SaveChanges` twice:

```vb
Using ts = New TransactionScope()
    Dim dcx = New MyDataContext
    Dim person1 = dcx.Persons.Find(128581)
    Dim person2 = dcx.Persons.Find(128603)
    dcx.Persons.Remove(person1)
    dcx.SaveChanges
    person2.NationalCode=person1.NationalCode '200362226
    dcx.SaveChanges
    ts.Complete()
End Using
```